# Styling tooltip in multi-line D3.js line chart

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

i have made a multi-line chart using D3.js with tooltips. Everything is working fine in this graph but i want to add styling to tooltips for all the charts in the graph but unable to do so.

```js
var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 30,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 40
  },
  width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var z = d3.scale.category20c();

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%LZ");

var data = [{
  data: [
    ["2016-01-20T05:31:17.000Z", 95.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:31:47.000Z", 95.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:32:17.000Z", 95.4, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:32:47.000Z", 96.1, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:33:17.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:33:47.000Z", 95.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:34:17.000Z", 95.5, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:34:47.000Z", 95.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:35:17.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:35:47.000Z", 95.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:36:17.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:36:47.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:37:17.000Z", 95.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:37:47.000Z", 95.5, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:38:17.000Z", 95.4, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:38:47.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:39:17.000Z", 96.0, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:39:47.000Z", 96.1, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:40:17.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:40:47.000Z", 96.0, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:41:17.000Z", 95.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:41:47.000Z", 94.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:42:17.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:42:47.000Z", 95.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:43:17.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:43:47.000Z", 96.0, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:44:17.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:44:47.000Z", 96.0, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:45:17.000Z", 95.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:45:47.000Z", 96.0, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:46:17.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:46:47.000Z", 96.0, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:47:17.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:47:47.000Z", 96.2, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:48:17.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:48:47.000Z", 95.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:49:17.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:49:47.000Z", 95.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:50:18.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:50:48.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:51:18.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:51:48.000Z", 95.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:52:18.000Z", 95.5, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:52:48.000Z", 95.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:53:18.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:53:48.000Z", 95.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:54:18.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:54:48.000Z", 95.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:55:18.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:55:48.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:56:18.000Z", 95.6, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:56:48.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:57:18.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:57:48.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:58:18.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:58:48.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:59:18.000Z", 95.6, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:59:48.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T06:00:18.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T06:00:48.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T06:01:18.000Z", 95.6, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T06:01:48.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T06:02:18.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T06:02:48.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T06:03:18.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T06:03:48.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T06:04:18.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T06:04:48.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T06:05:18.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T06:05:48.000Z", 95.7, {}]
  ],
  label: "a"
}, {
  data: [
    ["2016-01-20T05:31:17.000Z", 90.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:31:47.000Z", 91.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:32:17.000Z", 92.4, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:32:47.000Z", 90.1, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:33:17.000Z", 89.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:33:47.000Z", 91.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:34:17.000Z", 85.5, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:34:47.000Z", 93.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:35:17.000Z", 94.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:35:47.000Z", 93.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:36:17.000Z", 92.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:36:47.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:37:17.000Z", 92.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:37:47.000Z", 93.5, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:38:17.000Z", 93.4, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:38:47.000Z", 93.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:39:17.000Z", 93.0, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:39:47.000Z", 93.1, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:40:17.000Z", 93.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:40:47.000Z", 93.0, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:41:17.000Z", 93.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:41:47.000Z", 93.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:42:17.000Z", 92.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:42:47.000Z", 92.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:43:17.000Z", 93.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:43:47.000Z", 93.0, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:44:17.000Z", 93.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:44:47.000Z", 93.0, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:45:17.000Z", 93.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:45:47.000Z", 93.0, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:46:17.000Z", 93.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:46:47.000Z", 96.0, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:47:17.000Z", 92.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:47:47.000Z", 92.2, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:48:17.000Z", 92.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:48:47.000Z", 92.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:49:17.000Z", 92.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:49:47.000Z", 92.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:50:18.000Z", 93.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:50:48.000Z", 93.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:51:18.000Z", 92.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:51:48.000Z", 92.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:52:18.000Z", 92.5, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:52:48.000Z", 94.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:53:18.000Z", 94.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:53:48.000Z", 94.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:54:18.000Z", 94.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:54:48.000Z", 94.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:55:18.000Z", 94.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:55:48.000Z", 93.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:56:18.000Z", 94.6, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:56:48.000Z", 94.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:57:18.000Z", 93.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:57:48.000Z", 93.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:58:18.000Z", 93.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:58:48.000Z", 93.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:59:18.000Z", 93.6, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:59:48.000Z", 93.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T06:00:18.000Z", 93.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T06:00:48.000Z", 93.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T06:01:18.000Z", 93.6, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T06:01:48.000Z", 94.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T06:02:18.000Z", 94.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T06:02:48.000Z", 94.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T06:03:18.000Z", 94.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T06:03:48.000Z", 94.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T06:04:18.000Z", 94.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T06:04:48.000Z", 94.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T06:05:18.000Z", 94.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T06:05:48.000Z", 94.7, {}]
  ],
  label: "b"
}]


var x = d3.time.scale()
  .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
  .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(x)
  .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(y)
  .orient("left");

var line = d3.svg.line()
  .interpolate("monotone")
  .x(function(d) {
    return x(parseDate.parse(d[0]));
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return y(d[1]);
  });

var ary = [];
data.forEach(function(d) {
  ary.push(d.data);
});

x.domain(d3.extent(d3.merge(ary), function(d) {
  return parseDate.parse(d[0]);
}));

y.domain([
  d3.min(data, function(c) {
    return d3.min(c.data, function(v) {
      return v[1];
    });
  }),
  d3.max(data, function(c) {
    return d3.max(c.data, function(v) {
      return v[1];
    });
  })
]);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis);

var series = svg.selectAll(".series")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "series");

series.append("path")
  .attr("class", "line")
  .attr("d", function(d) {
    return line(d.data);
  })
  .style("stroke", function(d, i) {
    return z(i);
  });

series.append("text")
  .datum(function(d) {
    return {
      label: d.label,
      data: d.data[d.data.length - 1]
    };
  })
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + x(parseDate.parse(d.data[0])) + "," + y(d.data[1]) + ")";
  })
  .attr("x", 3)
  .attr("dy", ".35em");

var mouseG = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "mouse-over-effects");

mouseG.append("path") // this is the black vertical line to follow mouse
  .attr("class", "mouse-line")
  .style("stroke", "black")
  .style("stroke-width", "1px")
  .style("opacity", "0");

var lines = document.getElementsByClassName('line');

var mousePerLine = mouseG.selectAll('.mouse-per-line')
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "mouse-per-line");

mousePerLine.append("circle")
  .attr("r", 7)
  .style("stroke", function(d, i) {
    return z(i);
  })
  .style("fill", "none")
  .style("stroke-width", "1px")
  .style("opacity", "0");

mousePerLine.append("text")
  .attr("transform", "translate(10,3)");

mouseG.append('svg:rect') // append a rect to catch mouse movements on canvas
  .attr('width', width) // can't catch mouse events on a g element
  .attr('height', height)
  .attr('fill', 'none')
  .attr('pointer-events', 'all')
  .on('mouseout', function() { // on mouse out hide line, circles and text
    d3.select(".mouse-line")
      .style("opacity", "0");
    d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line circle")
      .style("opacity", "0");
    d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line text")
      .style("opacity", "0");
  })
  .on('mouseover', function() { // on mouse in show line, circles and text
    d3.select(".mouse-line")
      .style("opacity", "1");
    d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line circle")
      .style("opacity", "1");
    d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line text")
      .style("opacity", "1");
  })
  .on('mousemove', function() { // mouse moving over canvas
    var mouse = d3.mouse(this);
    d3.select(".mouse-line")
      .attr("d", function() {
        var d = "M" + mouse[0] + "," + height;
        d += " " + mouse[0] + "," + 0;
        return d;
      });

    d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
        console.log(width / mouse[0])
        var xDate = x.invert(mouse[0]),
          bisect = d3.bisector(function(d) {
            return d[0];
          }).right;
        var idx = bisect(d.data, xDate);

        var beginning = 0,
          end = lines[i].getTotalLength(),
          target = null;

        while (true) {
          target = Math.floor((beginning + end) / 2);
          var pos = lines[i].getPointAtLength(target);
          if ((target === end || target === beginning) && pos.x !== mouse[0]) {
            break;
          }
          if (pos.x > mouse[0]) end = target;
          else if (pos.x < mouse[0]) beginning = target;
          else break; //position found
        }

        d3.select(this).select('text')
          .text(y.invert(pos.y).toFixed(2));

        return "translate(" + mouse[0] + "," + pos.y + ")";
      });
  });
```

```css
text.inner-circle {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

text.inner-text {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-family: 'Metric Regular', 'Metric';
  text-align: center;
  font-style: normal;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

path {
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 2;
  fill: none;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: grey;
  stroke-width: 2;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.grid .tick {
  stroke: lightgrey;
  stroke-opacity: 0.7;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.grid path {
  stroke-width: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

I want to add a small white box at the top of each chart line with both x and y values. Please help me out.

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Lk4k2L8o/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

First make an text with id x-text and y-text append it to the group as shown below(as you want to display *both x and y values*).

```
mousePerLine.append("text").attr("id", "x-text")
  .attr("transform", "translate(10,3)");
mousePerLine.append("text").attr("id", "y-text")
  .attr("transform", "translate(10,23)");
```

Next you can show the values in the text created above on mouse move like this:

```
 //for y text on tooltip 
 d3.select(this).select('#y-text')
  .text("y: " + y.invert(pos.y).toFixed(2));
//make date in the format %H:%M:%S for x tooltip
d3.select(this).select('#x-text')
  .text("x: " + d3.time.format("%X")(xDate));
```

Next make a rectangle around the tooltip for styling:

```
mousePerLine.append("rect")
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", -10)
  .attr("width", 70)//width of rectangle
    .attr("height", 35)//height of rectangle
  .style("stroke", function(d, i) {
    return z(i);
  })
  .attr("class", "tooltip-container")//add class for styling rectangle
  .style("fill", "red")//give color red to it.
    .style("opacity", "0")
  .style("stroke-width", "1px");
```

working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/qvf8hn0u/)

Comment: Thank You for the solution but can you help me with one more thing? I want to remove the line when mouse moves and also want to position tooltip like that when graph intersects or comes closer to each other, in that case, tooltip rectangles, should not intersect each other and automatically change their alignment. is that possible?

Comment: @nikunj2512 its tough to get an algo to detect when tooltip are going to intersect so that is a tough call..:(